# Program terminated with signal 7, Bus error in yaml-cpp.0.3.0

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I have a C++ program which uses yaml-cpp (version 0.3.0).  When the program exits, I am getting a panic due to "Signal 7".

```
Program terminated with signal 7, Bus error.
#0  0x00007f766e658360 in void
std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<YAML::RegEx*>(YAML::RegEx*, YAML::RegEx*)
() from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-cpp.so.0.3
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007f766e658360 in void
std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<YAML::RegEx*>(YAML::RegEx*, YAML::RegEx*)
() from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-cpp.so.0.3
#1  0x00007f766e65843e in YAML::RegEx::~RegEx() () from
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-cpp.so.0.3
#2  0x00007f766d4b3df2 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f766d4b3e45 in exit () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f766d49beb4 in __libc_start_main () from
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000000000419cb1 in _start ()
```

Has anyone using yaml-cpp encountered this issue?  It seems the panic is encounters after my program exits (from Frame #3), and is in the process of unloading the library.  I looked into the source code for the destructor of RegEx, and it's basically a {}.  Any pointers to debug this issue would be highly appreciated.

(Additional info after edit)
I build the yaml-cpp0.3 library with debugging turned on.  I am now getting more info in the backtrace, but the panic is due to "Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.".   Following is the backtrace:

```
#0  0x0000000000ae05c6 in std::vector<YAML::RegEx, std::allocator<YAML::RegEx> >::~vector (this=0x2039353539414358, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:403
#1  0x0000000000adefd6 in YAML::RegEx::~RegEx (this=0x2039353539414350, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /u/aalmehdi/yaml/yaml-cpp/yaml_0.3.0/yaml-cpp/src/regex.h:28
#2  0x0000000000ae5d96 in std::_Destroy<YAML::RegEx> (__pointer=0x2039353539414350) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:95
#3  0x0000000000ae46ac in std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<YAML::RegEx*> (__first=0x2039353539414350, __last=0x5047207469622d36) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:105
#4  0x0000000000ae2457 in std::_Destroy<YAML::RegEx*> (__first=0x2039353539414350, __last=0x5047207469622d36) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:128
#5  0x0000000000ae0f5d in std::_Destroy<YAML::RegEx*, YAML::RegEx> (__first=0x2039353539414350, __last=0x5047207469622d36) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:155
#6  0x0000000000ae05dc in std::vector<YAML::RegEx, std::allocator<YAML::RegEx> >::~vector (this=0x37c2b48, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:403
#7  0x0000000000adefd6 in YAML::RegEx::~RegEx (this=0x37c2b40, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /u/aalmehdi/yaml/yaml-cpp/yaml_0.3.0/yaml-cpp/src/regex.h:28
#8  0x0000000000ae5d96 in std::_Destroy<YAML::RegEx> (__pointer=0x37c2b40) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:95
#9  0x0000000000ae46ac in std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<YAML::RegEx*> (__first=0x37c2b40, __last=0x37c2b80) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:105
#10 0x0000000000ae2457 in std::_Destroy<YAML::RegEx*> (__first=0x37c2b40, __last=0x37c2b80) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:128
#11 0x0000000000ae0f5d in std::_Destroy<YAML::RegEx*, YAML::RegEx> (__first=0x37c2b40, __last=0x37c2b80) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:155
#12 0x0000000000ae05dc in std::vector<YAML::RegEx, std::allocator<YAML::RegEx> >::~vector (this=0x37c2c28, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:403
#13 0x0000000000adefd6 in YAML::RegEx::~RegEx (this=0x37c2c20, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /u/aalmehdi/yaml/yaml-cpp/yaml_0.3.0/yaml-cpp/src/regex.h:28
#14 0x0000000000ae5d96 in std::_Destroy<YAML::RegEx> (__pointer=0x37c2c20) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:95
#15 0x0000000000ae46ac in std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<YAML::RegEx*> (__first=0x37c2c20, __last=0x37c2c40) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:105
#16 0x0000000000ae2457 in std::_Destroy<YAML::RegEx*> (__first=0x37c2c00, __last=0x37c2c40) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:128
#17 0x0000000000ae0f5d in std::_Destroy<YAML::RegEx*, YAML::RegEx> (__first=0x37c2c00, __last=0x37c2c40) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:155
#18 0x0000000000ae05dc in std::vector<YAML::RegEx, std::allocator<YAML::RegEx> >::~vector (this=0x25b26e8, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:403
#19 0x0000000000adefd6 in YAML::RegEx::~RegEx (this=0x25b26e0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /u/aalmehdi/yaml/yaml-cpp/yaml_0.3.0/yaml-cpp/src/regex.h:28
#20 0x00007ff78f7b2df2 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#21 0x00007ff78f7b2e45 in exit () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#22 0x00007ff78f79aeb4 in __libc_start_main () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#23 0x000000000041ca91 in _start ()
```

Comment: A) Trying to delete an invalid pointer will often cause the destructor crash. B) RegEx has a std::vector inside, you may br writing over it. Valgrind is your friend.

Comment: Can you post some example code that produces this error?

Comment: @JesseBeder Currently I am using yaml-cpp as part of a very large program.  The program is started and stopped as a service in Ubuntu (service mars start/stop).  The panic is encountered when the program is stopped.  It will take a while and some effort to come up with an example code which exhibits the issue.  I will post the sample code once I have something.

Comment: I compiled the library with debugging turned on.  I am now seeing more entries in the backtrace, and the cause of panic has changed to "Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.".  I would like to post the new bt here, but this comment space is pretty limited, and does not allow me to format.